# android intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP is not working

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm facing a problem and after trying a lot, I think I could not solve it.I hope someone can help me. Now the following is my situation: 
Activity A start Activity B , And Activity B starts itself(but the content in activity B has changed and this step may happened many times ). Now when I press back key,how Can I go to the Activity A directly .
this is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionNaireActivity.this, 
                            QuestionNaireActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);startActivity(intent);
```

I had try following:
1. use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` , it do go to activity A direct,but when B go to B the content does not change. 
2. use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP ,when goto Activity A,it reports a BUG like following:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo
 {who=null, request=1000, result=0, data=null} to activity  {com.snt.dauditapp/com.snt.dauditapp.Activity.SubTabFragments.QuestionnaireNavigationDetailActivity}: 
    java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Please suggest me. Thanks!

Comment: If you are getting a NullPointerException, it is likely that there is a different underlying problem. Follow the line number for that NPE, and make sure that a refreshed fragment/activity will not crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are looking for

> how Can I go to the Activity A directly

use the following on activity B

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        Intent i = new Intent(this, 
                            ActivityA.class);
               i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
               startActivity(i);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the CLEAR_TOP flag will remove any previous activities from the stack once you move to the new activity.
If you want to leverage the normal "back" behavior, in which clicking back returns to the previous activity, then you don't need to specify any flags on the intent. This is the default functionality.

My suggestion is: always start with activity A. If you need to move directly to B, make sure that activity A immediately directs you to B.
This way, clicking back in B will always return you to A.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thx for your answer.but my condition is:I cannot always start B with A. just for example:this is an exam parper,when you answer the question one then you can goto the next question.(the question in this example is just like activity B ,and there are many B.activity A is the login page)

Comment: That's ok though. I meant to say that even if you must start with B, use A to automatically transition to B. Otherwise, A can transition to B, and B can transition to itself endlessly. If you do it this way, you can rely on the back functionality to always bring you to the previous activity in the stack. Just remove the call to setFlags. That should work for you.

Comment: I'm sorry ,I'm still cannot undersatnd. canyou give me some code?

Comment: When you need to move to the next activity, simply call: startActivity(new Intent(QuestionNaireActivity.this, QuestionNaireActivity.class));

Comment: just remove :intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);??<hr/>

Comment: yes, you don't need it if you want to have "back" behavior. Setting this flag eliminates the back behavior.

Comment: NO it doesnot work.there are many B(B1 B2 B3 B4... just like many question in an answer paper). when I press back key in B4,it will go B3 then B2 then B1. At last go A.

Comment: I'm sorry. I misunderstood what you were trying to do. If you don't want B activities to be registered in the back stack, and clicking on back should direct you always to the first A activity, then whenever you call an intent for B activity, you should use the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY. This will make sure the new activity is not placed in the back stack. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

try to finish your old B activity while calling new one. Like this...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(QuestionNaireActivity.this, QuestionNaireActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```